# Connection timeout error for ActiveMQ Python STOMP client

Tags: python, timeout, stomp, activemq-artemis, durable-subscription

I am using the stomp.py 8.1.0 Python client to listen to Red Hat AMQ 7.4.1 (based on ActiveMQ Artemis), and I frequently get this error:

```
received an error {cmd=ERROR,headers=[{'message': 'AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /xx.xxx.xx.xx:57182 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed.'}],body=}
```

My client is:

```py
import sys
import os
import stomp

user = "a_user"
password = "a_password"
host = "a_host"
port = 61616
destination = "a_topic"

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
  
  def __init__(self, conn):
    self.conn = conn
    self.count = 0
    self.errors = 0
    self.start = time.time()
    self.stop = False
  
  def on_error(self, message):
    print('received an error %s' % message)
    self.stop = True
    
  def on_message(self, message):
    if message == "SHUTDOWN":
    
      diff = time.time() - self.start
      print("Received %s in %f seconds" % (self.count, diff))
      conn.disconnect()
      sys.exit(0)
      
    else:
      if self.count==0:
        self.start = time.time()
        
      self.count += 1
      
      print("Received %s messages." % self.count)
      
      if self.count > 10:
          self.stop = True

  def will_stop(self):
    return self.stop
    
conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports = [(host, port)])
listener = MyListener(conn)
conn.set_listener('', listener)
conn.connect(login=user,passcode=password, wait=True, headers = {'client-id': 'testname'})
conn.subscribe(destination=destination, id=30999, ack='auto', persistent=True, headers = {"activemq.subscriptionName":"testsub"})
print("Waiting for messages...")
while listener.count < 100 and not listener.will_stop(): 
  time.sleep(10)
```

Anyone knows whether my client is done correctly as a durable one, and should I revise my timeout setup, and how? A third-party system is publishing messages sparsely, this means my listener/subscriber will have to wait a long while to get a new message.

Comment: @JustinBertram, are you asking for the client (stomp) or server (activemq broker)? My stomp is 8.1. The broker is publishing message sparsely, this means my listener/subscriber will have to wait a long while to get a new message.

Comment: Redhat AMQ 7.4.1. It is a third-party system publishing the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broker is closing the connection because it is completely inactive and the time-to-live (i.e. TTL) is elapsing.

You need to configure [heart-beating](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#Heart-beating) as described in the STOMP specification. As noted in the spec:

> Heart-beating can optionally be used to test the healthiness of the underlying TCP connection and to make sure that the remote end is alive and kicking.

To do this with [stomp.py](https://pypi.org/project/stomp.py/) you can follow [the example in the documentation](http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/api.html#dealing-with-disconnects), e.g.:

```py
conn = stomp.Connection([(host, port)], heartbeats=(4000, 4000))
```

If the network connection between the client and the broker is not very reliably you could try increasing the heartbeats (e.g. `10000, 10000`) or you could try setting `heart_beat_receive_scale=2.0` when creating the connection or both.

Comment: This seems better, and I receive following after a long while:
heartbeat timeout: diff_receive=6.015999999945052, time=570601.281, lastrec=570595.265

Comment: How reliable is the network connection between the client and the broker? You could try increasing the heartbeats (e.g. `10000, 10000`) or you could try setting `heart_beat_receive_scale=2.0` when creating the connection or both.